# windows service to run a method at definite time interval in C++

Tags: c++, boost, windows-services, timer

I want to call a method periodically in a windows service built in C++. I am calling the method in SvcMain().

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    // The Services to run have to be added in this table.
    // It takes the Service Name and the name of the method to be called by SC Manager.
    // Add any additional services for the process to this table.
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[]= {{SVCNAME,(LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)SvcMain},{NULL,NULL}};

    // This call returns when the service has stopped. 
    // The process should simply terminate when the call returns.
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);  
    return 0;
}

void WINAPI SvcMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR *argv)
{
    ConnectToServer();
}
```

Q1. Is this going to fire ConnectToServer() all the time or only once? I just don't know how win service works.
Q2.I want ConnectToServer() to be fired every 15 mins. How can I do that ?

EDIT: How can I create an installer for this service?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's going to call SvcMain once. But you're not doing what you should in SvcMain. There's a good example on MSDN about [Writing a ServiceMain function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you copy that example, you'd write your code to call ConnectToServer inside the SvcInit function (inside the `while(1)` loop). You can get the 15 minute delay between calls by specifying 15 minutes as the timeout value in the call to `WaitForSingleObject`.

---

If ConnectToServer is a long running process, you should probably find a way of breaking it up and introducing more calls to `WaitForSingleObject` within it, so that your service responds in a timely fashion to Stop requests.

Comment: can i fire ConnectToServer() at a perticular time? I want it to be called every day at 6 pm.